# How to calculate probability if P>1?

Tags: probability, p-value, conditional-probability

** SORRY IF ITS BEEN ASKED BEFORE OR QUESTION TITLE IS UNCLEAR, NOOB STATS HERE **

I'm trying to interpret some data re causes of traffic accidents and in a file I got from the department of transport, it says that percentages may not add up to 100% because each factor may be considered along with others:

Cause 1 - Driver reaction error: 76%
Cause 2 - Fail to look properly: 47%
Cause 3 - Dangerous maneuver: 30%
... And the list goes on, till 80th cause/factor.

How do you calculate the probability of having the first 3 factors as causes in one accident?

Comment: That can't be done without information on their joint occurrence.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the dataset or print here it's head?

Comment: @NickCox Presumably, he could find bounds, though.

Comment: In these circumstances the bounds are hopelessly wide, are they not?